# How to wait until element is visible using TestFX?

Tags: java, javafx, dialog, testfx

I'm trying to use waitUntil() method from TestFX to wait until a dialog appears on the screen. I found the example provided by the [Wiki](https://github.com/TestFX/TestFX/wiki/Waiting), but it doesn't seem to work with me. Can anyone help me to figure this out?

Answer (score 3):

You can use this method also:

```
import org.testfx.util.WaitForAsyncUtils;

WaitForAsyncUtils.waitFor(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS, new Callable<Boolean>() {
    @Override
    public Boolean call() throws Exception {
        return find(".dialog-pane").isVisible();
    }
});
```

With this solution you can also define the TimeUnit.

Answer (score 2):

I managed to resolve this by using:

```java
import org.hamcrest.Matchers;
import org.loadui.testfx.controls.impl.VisibleNodesMatcher;

waitUntil(".dialog-pane", Matchers.is(VisibleNodesMatcher.visible()));
```

Comment: You can also pass timeout parameter in seconds:
waitUntil(".dialog-pane", Matchers.is(VisibleNodesMatcher.visible()), 10);